# Visual studio adds deleted resource string to usercontrol

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localization, devexpress, designer, resource-files

I have problem with my vs2010. I have a large project with a lot of localized user controls.

My problem is that if I have removed a string from my resource file (I have a resource file that hold a lot of strings and images), then sometimes when I switch languages in my user control, visual studio will add it "all over" my user control designer file.

It seems pretty random where it adds it. It can be added to as a ToolTip or ToolTip title on my devexpress gridviews, it can be added a Tag on a label, or on any number of string properties that I have not set. I have to go in and manually remove each line with the string to make my solution compilable again.

I know this is a sort of vague and unprecise question. I'm just hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pre-build event you can put this

> if exist "$(TargetPath).locked" del "$(TargetPath).locked" if exist
>   "$(TargetPath)" if not exist "$(TargetPath).locked" move
>   "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetPath).locked"

This has helped me.